# Algorithm for calculating similar stores based on weekly data

Tags: python, r, cluster-analysis, similarity, hierarchical-clustering

I have transaction level data for various stores which is aggregated at a weekly level. There are various variables such as sales, customer count etc for each store, now what I want to do is group similar stores together based on the weekly values for these variables. So the data set would look something like this:

```
Store . Sales . Cust_count . Week
X .     100 .   30 .         1
X .     200 .   40 .         2
Y .     80 .    30 .         1
Y .     70 .    15 .         2
```

Now my doubts is that if i directly use clustering algorithm like k-means on this data set then it would cluster similar data points which may belong to the same store instead of clustering similar stores. So how do i come up with a methodology or algorithm which compares week on week similarity between various stores and then produces a final similarity index between stores or cluster similar stores.

Comment: Transform your data to having one row (vector) per each store, with columns `Sales_1, Cust_count_1` per week 1, `Sales_2, Cust_count_2` per week 2 etc. And then use k-means.

Comment: It looks like a good solution on small data set but in my case the number of weeks and the number of variables are quite large which could lead to , too many attributes being created for each store. I am not sure if computationally k-means will be able to run on that.